# How to change the color of my h2 with h2:hover:after

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the color of my h2  with  `h2:hover:after` how can I do it? here's what I have so far.

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
}

h2:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 14%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;
}

h2:hover:after {
  width: 50%;
  color: darkgoldenrod;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-article">
  <h2>Technology</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to change the color of the h2 or of the after border ?

Comment: color changes the color of text. The after pseudo element has no text. I suspect you are wanting to change the border color not  the color.

Comment: @AHaworth No...I wanted to change the color of my text, but it is actually straight forward! h2:hover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing.

If you want to change the color of `h2` just use `h2:hover { color: darkgoldenrod }` , if you want to change the 'color' of the 'after' element, meaning the border-color, just use `h2:hover:after { border-color: darkgoldenrod}`

```css
h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
}

h2:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 14%;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid red;
}

h2:hover:after {
  width: 50%;
  border-color: darkgoldenrod;
}
/* change color of h2 */
h2:hover {
  color: darkgoldenrod;
  }
```

```html
<div id="main-article">
  <h2>Technology</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mihai T... I seen the code of the hover:after on a website somewherebut anyway it makes sense...

Comment: You need to learn how to ' read ' css selectors and it will all make sense :)